# C++ : get path's objects and print them

Tags: c++, file, directory, path

Im new to c++ so please dont judge.
What i need is to get the following path objects and then print them.

my path : `Server>Tracks> ...some files...`, the .sln and all the other files are at `Server` directory

This is my code. No errors are showing, but when im trying to print this directory i get nothing. whats wrong

```
// Takes the full path of the current directory and changes windows' path separation style from \ to / 
std::string Server::WindowsPathToForwardSlashes()
{
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::string::size_type fullPath = std::string(buffer).find_last_of("\\/");

    std::string windowsPath = std::string(buffer).substr(0, fullPath) + "\\tracks\\*";

    std::vector<std::string> spitList;
    std::string fixedPath;

    std::vector<std::string> splittedStrings = Split(windowsPath, '\\');

    // split windows' path
    for (int i = 0; i < splittedStrings.size(); i++)
    {
        //std::cout << splittedStrings[i] << std::endl;
        spitList.push_back(splittedStrings[i]);
    }

    // reassemble the path with forward slashes
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = spitList.begin(); i != spitList.end(); ++i)
    {
        fixedPath += *i + "/";
        //std::cout << fixedPath << std::endl;
    }
    fixedPath = fixedPath.substr(0, fixedPath.size() - 1);

    return fixedPath;
}
```

Comment: How about using `std::filesystem::path::generic_string` instead?

Comment: `Split(windowsPath, '\\');` -- If this code is supposed to return a `vector` of `std::string`, why do you need that `for (int i = 0; i < splittedStrings.size(); i++)` loop afterwards?  Aren't the strings already "splitted" into a vector?  Also, `fixedPath = fixedPath.substr(0, fixedPath.size() - 1);` -- There is no need to create a brand new string if you simply use `fixedPath.pop_back();`

Comment: *No errors are showing* -- If you mean compiler errors, all that means is that the code has no syntax errors -- it has no bearing on whether the program is logically correct. -- *but when im trying to print this directory i get nothing.* -- I see no "print" statements anywhere in the code you posted.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @eerorika in which line

Comment: Does `buffer` contain the expected value after you call `GetModuleFileName`?  There are two versions of `GetModuleFileName`, depending on what character set your program is compiled with.  Your program assumes that it's using `GetModuleFileNameA`.  This is where I would start looking [with my debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to investigate the problem.  And I would keep stepping through the program until I encounter something that's different from what I expect.

Comment: You should either step through your code with a debugger or add some diagnostic output. The goal of this is to determine the point at which any variable contains a value other than what you expect. To simplify this exercise, you might want to assign a known value to `buffer` instead of calling `GetModuleFileName()`.